# How to output sms on textview on sms Recieve?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I've made this simple app for recieving sms,When I receive a message I want to output this on my TextView,upuntil now for testing I was just doing
that inside a button .You recieve a message ,click on the button and you get the sms on textview.If I try to do this without a button ,at the start of compilation
I get a null reference exception.Can anyone help me on this ?

```
     //----------MainActivity.cs---------------
        
  using Android.App;
 using Android.OS;
 using Android.Support.V7.App;
 using Android.Runtime;
 using Android.Widget;
 using Android.Content;
 using Android.Telephony;
 using Android.Provider;
 using Android.Util;
 using Java.Lang;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using Xamarin.Essentials;
 using System;
 using Android;
 using Android.Support.V4.Content;
 using Android.Content.PM;
 namespace Sms_Receiver2
 {
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
 {
     public Receiver1 _receiver;            // Receiver class 
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
         // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
         SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
         TextView translatedPhoneWord = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TranslatedPhoneword);
         Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.TranslateButton);
         if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, Manifest.Permission.ReadSms) != (int)Permission.Granted)
         {
             RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.ReadSms, Manifest.Permission.SendSms, Manifest.Permission.ReceiveSms }, 0);
         }
         translateButton.Click += (s, e) =>
         {};

        translatedPhoneWord.Text = _receiver.message;// null reference   exception
     }
     public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
     {
         Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
         base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
     }
     protected override void OnResume()
     {
         base.OnResume();
         _receiver = new Receiver1();
         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
         filter.AddAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
         filter.AddAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER");
         RegisterReceiver(_receiver, filter);
     }
     protected override void OnPause()
     {
         base.OnPause();
         UnregisterReceiver(_receiver);
     }
     }
     }         
       //---------Reciever.cs -------------


 using Android.App;
 using Android.Content;
 using Android.OS;
 using Android.Runtime;
 using Android.Views;
 using Android.Widget;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using Android.Telephony;
 using Android.Provider;
 namespace Sms_Receiver2
 {
 [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS")]
 [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED", "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
 public class Receiver1 : BroadcastReceiver
 {
     public string message, address = "";
     public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
     public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
     {
         if (intent.HasExtra("pdus"))
         {
             var smsArray = (Java.Lang.Object[])intent.Extras.Get("pdus");
             foreach (var item in smsArray)
             {
                 var sms = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])item);
                 address = sms.OriginatingAddress;
                 message = sms.MessageBody;
                 Toast.MakeText(context, "Number :" + address + "Message : " + message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
             }
         }
           
         }
     }
     }
```

Comment: Can anyone help me on this ???

Comment: you are creating instance of Receiver1 _receiver in OnResume lifecycle method. Which be will called after OnCreate method. So, Instance of Receiver1 is not created. And you are trying to access Receiver1 instance before it created. Due to that you are getting null exception.

Comment: Ive posted another way to do this down in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight modification of your code works

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private SMSBroadcastReceiver _receiver;
        private TextView _smsTextView; //Textview where list of received sms will show

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            _smsTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.smstextview);

            _receiver = new SMSBroadcastReceiver();
            _receiver.SmsActionDelegate = InokeOnNewSMS;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.AddAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            filter.AddAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER");
            RegisterReceiver(_receiver, filter);
        }

        //this method will be invoked when new sms is received in the broadcast received
        public void InokeOnNewSMS(string address, string message)
        {
            _smsTextView.Text += $"{address} : {message}\n\n";
        }
    }


    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED", "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
    public class SMSBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public string message = "", address = "";
        public static readonly string INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        public Action<string, string> SmsActionDelegate;

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.HasExtra("pdus"))
            {
                var smsArray = (Java.Lang.Object[])intent.Extras.Get("pdus");
                foreach (var item in smsArray)
                {
                    var sms = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])item);
                    address = sms.OriginatingAddress;
                    message = sms.MessageBody;
                    SmsActionDelegate?.Invoke(address, message);
                    Toast.MakeText(context, "Number :" + address + "Message : " + message, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great ,but anyway I can avoid adding up the previous message with the new one ?

Comment: Yes, remove + (plus) from here _smsTextView.Text += $"{address} : {message}\n\n";

Comment: Instead of delegate you can use event also. If that does not fit for you. Then you can check for publisher subscriber pattens. for ex https://codewithshadman.com/publish-subscribe-design-pattern-in-csharp/